# Dispatching function multiple times in order to execute it with different parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

**Background**

I'm building a `React Native 0.64.1` app using `Redux 4.1.0`. This app fetches data from an API endpoint via POST which can take multiple "category" params. Only one value can be passed as category at a time, so in order to display data from multiple categories one would have to execute the function one time per category.

This is how the axios request is handled:

```
export const getData = (tk, value) =>
  apiInstance
    .request({
      url: ENDPOINTS.CATEGORIES,
      method: 'POST',
      data: qs.stringify({
        token: tk,
        category: value,
      }),
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error.message);
    });
```

This function is then executed via a redux action/reducer, etc.

The tricky part is that "value" is set by the user and can be changed at any point in time.
The front end meets this function in a certain screen where this happens:

```
useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(retrieveData(tk, value));
  }, [dispatch, value]);
```

**Problem & Question**

I've tried doing a for loop that would iterate through an array that contains the possible strings of text value could be, that would look something like this:

```
const arrayOfValues = ['A','B','C','D']
let value = null;
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) {
      value = arrayOfValues[i];
      dispatch(retrieveData(tk, value));
    }
  }, [dispatch, value]);
```

I know this is horrible and I'm just showing it because it's the only thing I could think about (and it doesn't even work).

An ideal solution would:

1. Execute the first request on load
2. Run a request once per item in an array WITHOUT deleting the previously called for data
3. Each time it runs it needs to update the "value" parameter.

> As a note about "retrieveData()", that is just the redux action.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**Solution by @rigojr**

This seems like it should work, but either I haven't expressed myself properly or there's something wrong with the answer. I'm guessing it's the former.

@rigojr proposed the following:

```js
    export const getData = (tk, values) => values.map((value) => apiInstance
      .request({
        url: ENDPOINTS.CATEGORIES,
        method: 'POST',
        data: qs.stringify({
          token: tk,
          category: value,
        }),
    }))
    
    Promise.all(getData(tk,values)) *****
    .then(responseValues => {
      // Dispatch the response, it will come an array of values response.
    })
    .catch(eer => {
      // Error handling
    })
```

Howeve, `values` in the line marked with many asterisks is inaccessible. I believe this is because previosuly I failed to mention that the whole Redux data flow happens in three separate files.

1. Dispatching the action: UI dispatches an action onLoad in App.js:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
              dispatch(retrieveData(tk, values));
          }, [dispatch, value]);
```

2. The action is ran in action.js file. It looks something like this:

> Note that I have added the Promise.all() in this screen, as it seems like the place where it should actually go, instead of the other one.

```js
    export const actionTypes = keyMirror({
      RETRIEVE_REQUEST: null,
      RETRIEVE_SUCCESS: null,
      RETRIEVE_FAILURE: null,
    });
    
    const actionCreators = {
      request: createAction(actionTypes.RETRIEVE_REQUEST),
      success: createAction(actionTypes.RETRIEVE_SUCCESS),
      failure: createAction(actionTypes.RETRIEVE_FAILURE),
    };
    
    export const retrieveData = (tk, values) => dispatch => {
      dispatch(actionCreators.request());
      Promise.all(getData(tk, values))
        .then(data => dispatch(actionCreators.success(data)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(actionCreators.failure(error)));
    };
```

3. Then there's the reducer, of course in reducer.js:

```js
    
    export const initialState = {
      loadingData: false,
      data: [],
      error: null,
    };
    
    const actionsMap = {
      [actionTypes.RETRIEVE_REQUEST]: state => ({
        ...state,
        loadingData: true,
      }),
    
      [actionTypes.RETRIEVE_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        loadingData: false,
        data: action.payload,
      }),
    
      [actionTypes.RETRIEVE_FAILURE]: (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        loadingData: false,
        error: action.payload,
      }),
    };
    
    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      const actionHandler = actionsMap[action.type];
      if (!actionHandler) {
        return state;
      }
      return actionHandler(state, action);
    };
```

4. Data is then accessed via a selector:

```js
const data = useSelector(state => state.data.data);
```

When running the code above, I am greeted with the following lovely error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...}).then(function (response)...')
```

And in the emulator, I get pointed in the direction of these lines of code:

```js
    export const getData = (tk, values) => values.map((value) => apiInstance
      .request({
        url: ENDPOINTS.CATEGORIES,
        method: 'POST',
        data: qs.stringify({
          token: tk,
          category: value,
        }),
    }))
```

More specifically, the emulator seems to think that the error has to do with value.map, as it points a little red arrow at "values" just before the method.

Any idea on what went wrong?

**Note**

Upon refresh the error might change, for example just now it has shown the same error message but it points in the direction of

```js
export const retrieveData = (tk, values) => dispatch => {
      dispatch(actionCreators.request());
      Promise.all(getData(tk, values))
        .then(data => dispatch(actionCreators.success(data)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(actionCreators.failure(error)));
    };
```

More specifically, the little red arrow points at getData.
Refreshing again, and the error points at

```js
    useEffect(() => {
              dispatch(retrieveData(tk, values));
          }, [dispatch, value]);
```

Refrsh once more and it just loses it and goes for a module, as shown in the image[image: picture showing native module error message]:

It doesn't go further from there. Just mind that every single time, the error message is  `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...}).then(function (response)...')`, it just points in a new direction.

**Solved in**

[Unable to perform .map whithin function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004726/unable-to-perform-map-whithin-function/68005145#68005145)

Comment: I think dispatch return a promise that can be used to call next value. So you start with first index and then when dispatch complete, start the next one until all values fetched.

Comment: @SaachiTech could you please point out which documentation I can read to understand that?

Comment: @luYSYA what about a `Promise.all()` ? you can have an array of promise calling every position in the array. and after all EPs response, you can map the values an return the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a `Promise.all()`:

```
export const getData = (tk, values) => values.map((value) => apiInstance
  .request({
    url: ENDPOINTS.CATEGORIES,
    method: 'POST',
    data: qs.stringify({
      token: tk,
      category: value,
    }),
}))

Promise.all(getData(tk,values))
.then(responseValues => {
  // Dispatch the response, it will come an array of values response.
})
.catch(eer => {
  // Error handling
})
```

Read more about `Promise.all()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: This seems like a sensible and intelligent solution. I'll look into it and let you know if it worked for me. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Howdy, @luYSYA you're very welcome. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm sorry to get back to you just now, I've had to switch priorities. tk and value are passed as params in a different file than the one where getData is declared. This means that tk whithin the call for the function in Promise.all() is inaccessible. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: after some tinkering I managed to come past that problem, but now I am getting this issue: TypeError undefined is not a function (near '...values.map...')

Comment: I've had to use the spread operator before values as it is an iterable array.

Comment: @luYSYA Hi!, did you solve the issue ? I advice to update the question in order to help you in a better way.

Comment: Hey @rigojr, I've just updated it in detail, can you please check it out? Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: @luYSYA did you try to console the `tk` and `values` arguments ? Looks like the error came from those variables.

Comment: It was a matter of placement of Promise.all. Thanks a lot for your answer, it pointed me in the right direction. In case you're interested, this is the link to the newer question I posted and solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004726/unable-to-perform-map-whithin-function/68005145#68005145

Comment: @luYSYA nice to hear that! you're very welcome!