# Unable to perform .map whithin function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, array.prototype.map

**Background**

I'm building a React-Redux application which, amongst other things, has to handle some axios calls to a private API. Said API is not under my control, and I cannot modify anything. One of the axios requests is performed by a function, let's call it "getData". This request uses POST as its method and requires a parameter "category", this accepts only one value at a time. Thing is sometimes I need to perform say three requests at a time and I intend to do so programatically rather than hardcoding a request for each possible request, as the number of available categories is high.

**What I intent to build**

A function which performs a request, taking in two parameters, one is a token, the other one is an array of possible values to be passed as the "category" param. The function should run once per value in the array and return a single array of objects which holds all of the "products" brought over from the backend.

**What I've built already**

```
export const getData = (tk, values) =>
  values
    .map(value =>
      apiInstance.request({
        url: ENDPOINTS.ENDPOINT,
        method: 'POST',
        data: qs.stringify({
         token: token,
         category: value,
        }),
      }),
    )
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error.message);
    });
```

Above is the actual request and next is the redux action:

```
export const actionTypes = keyMirror({
  RETRIEVE_REQUEST: null,
  RETRIEVE_SUCCESS: null,
  RETRIEVE_FAILURE: null,
});

const actionCreators = {
  request: createAction(actionTypes.RETRIEVE_REQUEST),
  success: createAction(actionTypes.RETRIEVE_SUCCESS),
  failure: createAction(actionTypes.RETRIEVEO_FAILURE),
};

export const retrieveData = (tk, values) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(actionCreators.request());
  Promise.all(getData(tk, values))
    .then(data => dispatch(actionCreators.success(data)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(actionCreators.failure(error)));
};
```

And the reducer:

```
export const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  error: null,
};

const actionsMap = {
  [actionTypes.RETRIEVE_REQUEST]: state => ({
    ...state,
    loading: true,
  }),

  [actionTypes.RETRIEVE_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    data: action.payload,
  }),

  [actionTypes.RETRIEVE_FAILURE]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    loadingPublic: false,
    error: action.payload,
  }),
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const actionHandler = actionsMap[action.type];
  if (!actionHandler) {
    return state;
  }
  return actionHandler(state, action);
};
```

> Note that all of these are in separate files.

**Problem**

I'm getting the error message `undefined is not a function (near '...}).then(function (response)...')` and this points to values.map((value) =>

**Question**

As far as I understand, .map can recieve a short-arrow function such as this as its first parameter. Values is an array of strings, so it should work in theory. What am I missing?

Comment: map returns array of promises not a promise, try `Promise.all(values.map....)`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I've tried that just now, doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski actually it does avoid the error message now, I had just placed some parentheses in the wrong place. Anyhow, the function now returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you map your `values` to a list of Promises.

However, `.then()` is not callable on a list (`[Promise, Promise, ...]`) in your case. In fact, `.then` will be `undefined` which is exactly what the error message tells you.

Instead, try to wrap `values.map(...)` in a `Promise.all(...)`.
This will wait for all promises to resolve before calling `.then(...)`.

**Keep in mind that the `response` passed to `.then(...)` will actually also be a list!**

So you want to do something like this:

```
Promise.all(
  values
    .map(value =>
      apiInstance.request({
        url: ENDPOINTS.ENDPOINT,
        method: 'POST',
        data: qs.stringify({
         token: token,
         category: value,
        }),
      }),
    )
)
.then(responses => {
  // responses is a list!
  return responses.map(response => response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
  return Promise.reject(error.message);
});
```

Comment: I cannot begin to express how much you've helped me. Been hardstuck on this for  days on end now, this is just wonderful. Thanks a whole lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
export const getData = (tk, values) =>
  values
    .map(value =>
      apiInstance.request({
        url: ENDPOINTS.ENDPOINT,
        method: 'POST',
        data: qs.stringify({
         token: token,
         category: value,
        }),
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return Promise.reject(error.message);
      })
    );
```